# How to add css/images to the email content?

Tags: html, css, email

My friend has challenged me to send him an email which contains a halloween design with a few pictures, orange background and with a short text (long story, dont ask me why). I have searched a bit on the internet, but didnt really find anything that could help me. Can you give me tips on how to do this?

Comment: What _tip_ you mean? The only one is to use inline styles. Basics of HTML&CSS you have to study yourself.

Comment: prepare a simple page with basic markup (tables) and send it to your friend (using a mail client or with online service, like putsmail)

Comment: If I paste the html into the email nothing special happens... I just see my code

Comment: which client are you using?

Answer (score 1):

### What you CAN'T do:

- **Include a  section with styles.** Apple Mail.app supports it, but Gmail and Hotmail do not, so it's a no-no. Hotmail will support a style section in the body but Gmail still doesn't.
- **Link to an external stylesheet.** Not many email clients support this, best to just forget it.
- **Background-image / Background-position.** Gmail is also the culprit on this one.
- **Clear your floats.** Gmail again.
- **Margin.** Yep, seriously, Hotmail ignores margins. Basically any CSS positioning at all doesn't work.
- **Font-anything.** Chances are Eudora will ignore anything you try to declare with fonts.

### What you CAN Do:

In two words, **inline styles**. It's not as awful as you might think, since we are basically developing a one-off email, inline styles are not nearly as egregious as using them on a website. Need a big green title for a block of text?

```
<h3 style="color: #1c70db;">NOW $159</h3>
```

- **The big can-do is images.** Think creatively on what you can do with images.
- **Since you will be using tables, think gridular.** Grids are designers friends, there is lots you can do with a grid.

There are a great deal of online resources which you can use to help. Ultimately, you can only do inline styles.

Allowed Email Styling: [Documentation](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/)

Reference For Above Text: [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/using-css-in-html-emails-the-real-story/)